# Are you able to use the "+" in the output of a user input list in Python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am trying to get familiar with list and arrays in python and I was just wondering, can you add the "+" sign in the output of a user_input list? I am aware on calculating the total and also displaying the list but not sure if I can make it that way.

example: 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 = 30

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking.  Are you trying to print the values of a list seperated by `+` plus signs?

Comment: yes, that's exactly it. so if the user inputs a set of numbers when the output is displayed is there a way for "+" to separate each input.

Comment: A simpler way would be `' + '.join(map(str, your_list))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what Patrick Haugh said is correct, then what I think you would want is something like:

```
l = []
for i in range(5): # Can be changed to how many numbers you want
    while True:
        try:
            l.append(float(input("Number: ")))
            break
        except ValueError: # If user input is not a number
            print('Must be a number')

for i in l: # Iterates through the list
    print(i, end = '') # end = '' means the printing stays on the same line
    if i != l[-1]: # if i is not equal to the last value in the list
        print(' + ', end = '')
    else:
        print(' = '+str(sum(l))) # prints '=', then the sum of the list
```

Comment: Instead of answering based on the off-change that a guess by another user might be correct, it's best to *wait* for the OP to clarify.

Comment: Okay, will consider this next time. It was also what I assumed was most likely the question also. In other circumstances, I would not have answered this question.